# How to declare n linked lists using a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to get n from the user which will decide the number of linked lists.
I will add elements to these linked lists, create a vector of linked lists and pass the vector to a UDF.
I am unable to declare n linked lists using a for loop itself.

Comment: Do you know how to construct *one* linked list?

Comment: Yes, the code would be like, Node* head = NULL; and I can heep o adding elemnts to these linked list using the code Node* new_node = new Node(); new_node->data = value; new_node->next = NULL; head = new_node;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from the question, maybe this will work for you.

Just initialize a vector and keep pushing the new Lists in it.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
    
    Node (int data) {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

vector<Node*> createLists(int n) {
    vector<Node*> lists;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        Node* node = new Node(100 + i);
        lists.push_back(node);
    }
    return lists;
}


int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<Node*> lists = createLists(n);
    return 0;
}
```

You can create an `insertElement` method to add items in each linkedlist in the vector

Comment: Thanks Ankit, This worked like a charm !!

Comment: Hi, I did upvote, please let me know if anything else required :)

Comment: Well, for n lists, I like to have a naming convention like node1, node2, .... noden. I tried using Node* "node"+i.tostring() = new Node(), this din't work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You can't dynamically change variable names. You can think it is as, lists[i] = new Node(value), on the 0th index would be the first list, 1st index the second and so on.

Comment: @Stuti: You accepted Ankit's answer, but didn't actually upvote -- they're 2 different things. Both are optional of course, but always appreciated :)

Comment: Done, Thanks for pointing out. Always ready to do the needful !